# Emacs opened in terminal on an Ubuntu server does not show colors

Tags: command-line, colors, emacs

I am connecting to an Ubuntu server from the terminal via `ssh -Y ...`. When I open Emacs via `emacs` in a separate window, I see the color theme that I chose in my `~/.emacs` setup file (which is why I believe my problem is not an Emacs problem). However, when I open Emacs in the terminal (`emacs -nw`), I see no colors anymore. My `~/.emacs` is set up as on another server (CentOS) and there the colors show up. What could be the problem?

I tried a couple of things, such as connecting via `ssh -t -Y`, but nothing worked. `ls` shows colors in the terminal, so that's not the problem either.

In case this helps: If I open Emacs on the server in a separate window, I see the error message `Error (frameset): Font 'tty' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You may have found the answer already, but this question comes up pretty high in search results, so I want to come back around and make sure it has an answer.)

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950/how-to-make-emacs-terminal-colors-the-same-as-emacs-gui-colors) has a pretty good answer. If you just need to make a one-off edit, you can use

```
$ TERM=xterm-256color emacs $filename
```

That's a lot of characters to foul up. For my own workflow, I've just set up a permanent alias using [this guide from nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/).

Putting the two together, you can append `alias colormacs='TERM=xterm-256color emacs'` to ~/.bash_aliases (creating it if it isn't there already).

(I called mine 'colormacs' because I don't like overloading existing commands with aliases. You can call yours 'emacs' instead if you don't want to work against muscle memory.)

To load your new alias, run

```
$source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then you can just

```
colormacs $fileName
```